# MySQL Update with PHP not working how i wanted it to

Tags: php, mysql

Hi this is my first post so please excuse any errors

Background if this helps 
i've created several pages for a website 
submit form - puts data in to database - all working ok 
summary page - pulls through elements of database - all working ok 
edit page - this is where my problem is

my problem 
when creating a edit page it does not pull through the updated variable from the form and just updates the database with a empty field

so here is the code

edit.php

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$var_value = $_GET['id'];

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
?>
<form action="/update.php" method="post">
<label>Property Title
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row[title]?>" />
<form method='get' action='update.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value= "<?php echo $row[id]?>" >
<input type='submit' class='button radius' value='update' >

</form>


</label>
```

so that should display whats currently in the database then when a user changes it they click update and it should up date in the database

here is the update.php

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$title =$_POST['title'];
$var_value = $_GET['id'];

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE aparthousesalerent SET title='$title' WHERE id  = '$var_value' ";

echo $var_value;
echo $title;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

i added in the extra line of echo $var_value and echo $title; to check if that worked and it did but it still doesn't pass it through to the database

thanks for looking

Comment: What does your select statement look like? Does it work?

Comment: you're using nested forms in the first body of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/update.php" method="post">
<label>Property Title
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row[title]?>" />
<form method='get' action='update.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value= "<?php echo $row[id]?>" >
<input type='submit' class='button radius' value='update' >

</form>
```

as you can see there are nested form 
So, remove the form and make method post because you are using $_POST in php file.

```
<form action="/update.php" method="post">
<label>Property Title
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row[title]?>" />
<input type='hidden' name='id' value= "<?php echo $row[id]?>" >
<input type='submit' class='button radius' value='update' >

</form>
```

and use one either GET or POST

```
$title =$_POST['title'];
$var_value = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: many thanks for your help but i've updated my code and its still not working